# CSS Flex changes order positioning of text elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How does flex affect the positioning and order of text elements?

In a simple example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>My Site Name</h1>
    <br>
    <p>Welcome to the website</p>
  </header>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
</body>

</html>

header {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;

}

h1, p {
    display: inline;
    text-align: justify;
    color: white;
}
```

if I comment out flex I get the expected  display order of text

```
My Site Name
Welcome to the website
```

However with flex enabled I get

```
                            Welcome to the website
My Site Name
```

[plnkr flex](http://plnkr.co/edit/tU6eDJ2dRhPyJ4reHcyS?p=catalogue)

**EDIT**
Based on answer of display issue below this is a solution

```
header h1, p {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: green;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help a little:
[image: h1 highlighted with chrome dev]

When you have `display:flex` you are creating a flexbox with 3 child elements:

- `<h1>`
- An anonymous text element containing a single line break
- `<p>`

These elements are laid out left-to-right and the anonymous text element has 0 width and height. This is what it looks like if I put printable text before and after the `<br>`:

[image: text around br]

Comment: What is the new way of grouping in flex I can see box-flex-group but its deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-flex-group